# Accessing different elements in an array

Tags: c++, c++11

in `for(auto e : elem)`  I am trying to figure how to access element e-1. while in pre- C++ 11 it would have just been `elem[e-1]` I am sure that has to be a c++ 11 equivalent.

Comment: Here e is element, and not the index. In case you want to use index, you should continue to use that pre C++11 for loop

Comment: Here, `e` is not an index, it is one of the elements in `elem`. If you need to access multiple elements at a time you should use the classical syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you might do

```
for (auto [p, n] : ranges::view::zip(v, v | ranges::view::drop(1))) {
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c0c5cd8ccae81e3)

Answer (score 0):

Those two do vastly different things:

```
for(auto e : elem)
```

is syntactic sugar for a loop the iterates through the whole collection `elem`, whereas

```
elem[e - 1]
```

is accessing a single element of `elem` at the given index `e - 1`.

C++11 didn't remove access by index nor is it considered bad practice, because sometimes you don't have any other choice for implementing an algorithm.